# Wheel noise that's evading me

Tags: noise, nissan, steering, grinding

I recently had to downgrade in life. So I got a 2005 Nissan Altima 3.5 and aside from some expected repairs on an old car, it's in surprisingly good condition.

My issue though is with the front drivers side wheel. There's a rotating grinding/scraping noise. It's only slightly present while traveling straight and sometimes I don't hear it at all. When it turn 2/5ths or more to the right it's very noticeable and seems to go away if I'm turning to the left. It also picks up frequency with wheel speed. Almost sounds like a brake pad worn down to the steel backing (it's not, just replaced those). The dust plate was a bit close to the rotor so I bent it back into place.

The symptoms are very few so here's a list of what it's not doing:
-No clicking in any position
-No wobble, shakeing, or noticable vibration in the steering wheel
-No pulling to either side even when I let go of the steering wheel
-No play with I try to move the rotor whole the car is in the air (9 & 3 position and also 12 & 6 position, tried both)
-CV axle has no play when I try to move it in or out from the transmission, boots are in pristine condition
-Nothing is touching the tire/wheel while it's on the ground. No obvious signs of anything touching when the geometry changes

I did noticed the rubber around the tie rod ends has seen better days. Plus the steering feels... loose (came from a Mazda so I'm used to very responsive "sporty" steering). I don't think this is a tire rods issue though. This is a bit long but any help is appreciated. Recovering from a divorce doesn't leave much money to play with. I'd prefer not to have to replacing everything to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Given the lack of play and the fact that it's only really present when turning right it sounds very much like wheel bearing to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a hunch but... Rotate the tires, re-test.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since you posted about this problem—did you ever solve it?

My thought would be to re-visit your break pad job. Pry open the caliper, remove the pads, clean, inspect, and re-lube the caliber, then carefully reassemble everything with attention to detail and see if that resolves the symptoms.

I read somewhere once, maybe here, that quickly performed "pad slap jobs" are the most frequent reason people return to the shop after getting brake work. I once did a "pad slap" on my Blazer and had a similar grinding noise that would come from only one wheel, and I would only hear it when stopping slowly. But it went away on its own after a couple days driving to work, and before I had a chance to address it.

Also of note: [Grinding noise while driving](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/33596/grinding-noise-while-driving)